# SQL query employee and task table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an employee and a task table like this:

```
Table employees
  id not null primary key,
  name
```

```
Table Tasks
  id primary key,
  author id not null references employees (id),
  assigneeid references employees (id)
```

I am trying to write a query that would return task id, author name, and assignee name and if there is no assignee name then I want to return null. FYI, this is not a homework question but I'm learning backend development and I need to brush up my sql skills.

UPDATE:
Here is the expected output

```
-- Expected output (in any order):
-- id  author  assignee
-- ----------------------
-- 1   Richard
-- 2   Lily    Richard
```

Comment: Did you just provide sample output without any sample input? Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for two `left join`s:

```
select t.*, eau.name as author, eas.name as assignee
from tasks t left join
     employees eau
     on eau.id = t.author_id left join
     employees eas
     on eas.id = t.assignee_id;
```

Comment: Could you please explain it? Also If I were to get my expected output (see the update)? how would I do that?

Comment: @Saad . . . Why would you want the results in two separate rows rather than in a single row?